# How to edit metric in order to get the latest date?

Tags: gooddata

I'm trying to get the latest Date group by an attribute in mm/dd/yyyy format.
My code is:

```
select MAX(Date (Ticket Created Date)) BY EntityID
```

I've already tried to edit “Metric format” to “mm/dd/yyyy” format, but I wasn't successful. Do you have any better idea how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your metric returns a number (`id` of the day), not the date in the `mm/dd/yyyy` format. You can use a custom number formatting to change the display in the numeric expression. Detailed information can be found in the [documentation](https://help.gooddata.com/doc/en/dashboards-and-insights/maql-analytical-query-language/maql-use-cases-and-tutorials/finding-min-and-max-dates-using-date-arithmetic).

There you'll find the following example

```
SELECT MAX ((SELECT (10000 * MAX(Year (Date)))
                    + (100 * MAX(Month (Date)))
                    + (MAX(Day of Month (Date))) BY <connection point>))
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(Date (Date), <connection point>) BY Year (Date), ALL OTHER) > 0
```

This shows the dates in the `yyyymmdd` format, so you need to tweak it a bit to create `mm/dd/yyyy`:

```
SELECT (1000000 * MAX(Month (Date))
        + 10000 * MAX(Day of Month (Date))
        + MAX(Year (Date)))
WHERE ...
```

You can then set the format to `00/00/0000`. But note that sorting this value is not easy, unlike the `yyyymmdd`.